# WebApi 2 and OData controller - cast exception during route configuration, GetEdmModel not understood

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata, odata-v4

I have a controller that I've built (extending from System.Web.Http.Odata.ODataController) and I think it's going to work fine - it's mostly based on pure scaffolding provided by my Visual Studio IDE.

The application will build, but, errors out during application start-up. When it goes to perform the initial route configuration, it fails on the last line of this WebApiConfig class in my App_Start folder - the call to `config.MapODataServiceRoute` throws an InvalidCastException because the value of `builder.GetEdmModel()` isn't understood:

```
Imports System.Web.Http
Imports System.Web.Http.Cors
Imports System.Web.Http.OData.Builder
Imports System.Web.OData.Extensions

Public Class WebApiConfig
    Public Shared Sub Register(ByVal config As HttpConfiguration)
    ' Web API configuration and services

    'enable cross orgin scripting 'CORS'
    Dim cors = New EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*")
    config.EnableCors(cors)

    ' Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes()

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name:="DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate:="api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults:=New With {.id = RouteParameter.Optional}
    )


    Dim builder As New ODataConventionModelBuilder
    builder.EntitySet(Of BusinessOrder)("BusinessOrder")
    config.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", Nothing, builder.GetEdmModel())
    End Sub
End Class
```

Here's the specific language of the InvalidCastException:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.Data.Edm.Library.EdmModel' to type 'Microsoft.OData.Edm.IEdmModel'.
```

Hmmm.. the docs for [ODataConventionModelBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.odata.builder.odataconventionmodelbuilder.getedmmodel(v=vs.118).aspx) and [MapODataServiceRoute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn725914(v=vs.118).aspx) seem to indicate I'm dealing with compatible types. If I read the error right, I'm getting back an instance of `Microsoft.Data.Edm.Library.EdmModel` from the call to GetEdmModel, which I would think ought to be conformant to the IEdmModel interface, per the docs.

Here's my web application's NuGet `packages.config` - hopefully this helps you understand the libraries being referenced by my web app:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Antlr" version="3.4.1.9004" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery" version="1.10.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery.UI.Combined" version="1.11.4" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery.Validation" version="1.11.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="knockoutjs" version="2.3.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Cors" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.OData" version="5.6.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData" version="5.5.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Edm" version="5.6.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.OData" version="5.6.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.OData.Core" version="6.11.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.OData.Edm" version="6.11.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Spatial" version="6.11.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Modernizr" version="2.6.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.8" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="System.Spatial" version="5.6.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="WebGrease" version="1.5.2" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

Comment: Thankful for @TomOrton's clarification below showing the differences b/t using OData v3 and v4. I'm sure this was *part* of my problem, even though it did not immediately *solve* my problem. I decided to upgrade one of my NuGet references, by running this command: `Update-Package Microsoft.OData.Core` (which put the 3 packages that were at 6.11.0 up to 6.12.0) and that seems to have alleviated my woes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to upgrade one of my NuGet references, by running this command: Update-Package Microsoft.OData.Core (which put the 3 packages that were at 6.11.0 up to 6.12.0)

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing versions of OData. The namespace System.Web.Http.OData is for v3 and the namespace System.Web.OData is for v4.

```
Imports System.Web.Http.OData.Builder
Imports System.Web.OData.Extensions
```

I don't know which version you are trying to use but it should be consistent. Try changing both to Http

```
Imports System.Web.Http.OData.Builder
Imports System.Web.Http.OData.Extensions
```

or both to not have Http

```
Imports System.Web.OData.Builder
Imports System.Web.OData.Extensions
```

Comment: I changed my WebApiConfig.vb `Imports` along with my api controller class' `Imports` statements and the solution still hangs at the same line. Same error message. Maybe I need to clean up my NuGet package references?

Comment: That sounds like a good idea, you should be able to get there by just changing namespaces etc but that might be the fastest way to do it as it will give errors if anything hasn't been moved over. Let me know how it goes!

Comment: btw, I'm trying to use version 4.. 
Originally, when I scaffolded my api controller - it gave me some code to put into the WebApiConfig, (specifically, `config.Routes.MapODataRoute("odata", "odata", builder.GetEdmModel())`) and when I went to paste in this suggested  code snippet, Intellisense told me it was obsolete. That's when I changed out the obsolete method call to the suggested extension method `MapODataServiceRoute` which is apparently OData v 4

Comment: I voted this answer 'up' as it was helpful, but, it did not fully resolve my issue. See my comment on my OP